# iPad keyboard to hide but leave input field focused

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

I have a field auto-focused to listen for a value but it activates an iPad keyboard, which I need to hide. When I use

```
document.activeElement.blur();
```

it works, but my field loses focus. When I make my field be focused again, a keyboard shows up again.

How to have a focused field on a page ready to take any input (I use it to listen for a scanner output) but keep iPad's keyboard be hidden all the time?

Comment: May I ask why the field has to have auto-focus?

Comment: Yes, it listens for scanner output

Comment: You cannot make an input first responder *and* hide the keyboard.